# Inverse-square relationship and seeing stars from far away: Is there maximum distance from which we can see a star?

Tags: optics, astronomy, radiation

The question is:

Taking into account as obstacle only [inverse-square relationship](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/outreach/education/senior/cosmicengine/stars_luminosity.html). Does there exist border distance below which we can see a star and above which we can not?

[image: inverse-square_law]

From my understanding in some great (infinite?) distance from radiation emitter, there would be single photon for few square kilometers or even millions of square kilometers (depending on distance). If I am right, we would not be able to see object emitting it. Am I right?

If so, are there potential objects in the cosmos we are not seeing because of the law **and not** because their light did not reach us yet?

How far would these objects have to be (taking some average star as an example)?

Edit:
Answering these questions, take into consideration technology which is available today please. :)

Comment: surely this eventually depends on the quality of your detectors and, if the object is very faint, how patient you are for photons to arrive.

Comment: That's right, I added a paragraph stating that answers should take into account available technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_distant_astronomical_objects) to see the most distant astronomical objects ever seen. Obviously, it depends on the luminosity of the object. The brighter it is, the farther away it can be seen from; that's why all the farthest objects are galaxies. They are over 13 Gly from earth (~$9.5\dot{}10^{24}$ m).

The farthest *star* we've ever seen is apparently SDSS (Sloan Digital Sky Survey) J1229+1122, which is 55 Mly from earth (~$5.2\dot{}10^{23}$ m). However, that is a blue supergiant, not an average star.

I don't think this answers your question though. Let's look at how far away an average star would need to be to have the same brightness as the faintest thing we've ever observed. The faintest object we've ever recorded has an apparent magnitude of ~+31.5 $^{[1]}$ (the magnitude scale is weird, it goes backwards and is logarithmic).

If we take the Sun, a very average star, how far away would it need to be before its apparent magnitude "dropped" to +31.5? The distance modulus equation is

$$
m-M=5 \log_{10} (\frac{r}{10})
$$
where $m$ is the apparent magnitude, $M$ is the absolute magnitude, and $r$ is the distance in parsecs. The sun has an absolute magnitude $M_\odot = 4.83$, and so if we set $m_\odot=31.5$,

$$
26.67=5 \log_{10} (\frac{r}{10})
$$

$$
r=2158000 \textrm{ pc}
$$

So, the sun would need to be $2158000$ pc ($6.7\dot{}10^{22}$ m) away from us to have the same magnitude as the faintest object ever seen.

---

1 https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1931, from Wikipedia

Comment: To fill up on your answer. 2'158'000 pc or 7'038'455 ly is AROUND the distance we are not able to see sun-like objects. Looking at it from the intergalactic perspective makes it not that far (closest Galaxy, the M31, is around 2'500'000 ly away from us) and we often are looking into much deeper cosmos.  So answering my main question: Yes, there are a lot of objects we are not seeing because of inverse-square relationship (we would need better telescopes to be able to see them).

Comment: That is true, but there are not a lot of free-floating stars that are not a part of galaxies. The number of intergalactic stars we've found is on the order of several hundred to several thousand, whereas an average galaxy contains around a trillion stars. Most stars are in galaxies, or at least in clusters, which makes it easier to spot them, even if we can't resolve the individual stars. So we're not missing *too* much (in a relative sort of sense).